# How can I have an <input type=… attribute that varies on instantiations of a Svelte component while having its value in the reactivity system?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a FormRow component that looks, roughly, like this (the styling and layout information, which is why I want a component, is removed here for brevity):

```
<script>
  export let label;
  export let type;
  export let value;
</script>
<input type={type} bind:value={value}>
```

and it is used like this:

```
<FormRow title="Email: " type="email" value={email}/>
<FormRow title="Username:"  type="text" value={username}/>
<FormRow title="Password: " type="password" value={password}/>
<FormRow title="Confirm Password: " type="password" value={confirmPassword}/>
```

with the intention being to access the email, username, password, and confirmPassword variables in JS when the form is submitted, and possibly to use reactivity to add input validation (in addition to server-side validation, of course). But, when I try to compile this, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/_components/FormRow.svelte
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader/index.js):
Error: ValidationError: 'type' attribute cannot be dynamic if input uses two-way binding (31:22)
29:         {title}
30:     </label>
31:     <input id="input" type={type} bind:value={value}>
```

I think that I understand what the issue is (type and value can't both be set via the reactivity system), but I don't see how to accomplish what I want (a reusable and versatile FormRow component). I thought that there might be some other way to set the type attribute for each FormRow instance, since I don't need it to change during runtime for any particular instance, but I could not find any technique to have it vary on a per-component basis like this in the Svelte documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the input type, Svelte will use a different event listener when binding to the element. For instance, `bind:value` on an `<input type="text">` listens to the input event for updates, while `bind:checked` on an `<input type="checkbox">` listens to the change event. Svelte needs to know what type the input is at compile time to generate these listeners, which is why it won't let the type attribute be dynamic when you use two-way binding.

If you want a dynamic input type, you will need to generate the listeners yourself to update the value. Assuming you will only be using types that dispatch an `input` event when their `value` is updated, you can do the following:

```html
<!-- FormRow.svelte -->
<script>
    export let label;
    export let type;
    export let value = '';
    
    function handleInput(e) {
        value = e.target.value;
    }
</script>
<label><input type={type} value={value} on:input={handleInput}> {label}</label>

<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import FormRow from './FormRow.svelte';
    let value = 'hello';    
</script>

<p>
    Current value: {value}
</p>
<FormRow label="test" type="text" bind:value={value} />
```

Comment: I have this technique implemented in my code base, but when the input tag is initialized the `value` variable is set to undefined. It's not difficult to add a default empty string, but what about when the client loads a value into the input (for example, a saved password)?

Comment: The undefined case is a good find, I'll add an empty string default to the answer. The bound value still seems to update when the client inputs a value -- I even tried loading a saved password from my password manager. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: I don't think that the behavior in any single browser is sufficient. I'm concerned about whether or not web standards guarantee that they'll emit a change event whenever they autofill. If there's no standard, then relying on it seems risky as it could change in the browser arbitrarily or a different browser may do it differently.